# How do I syntaxcially correctly implement an interface with type<K extends Comparable<K>, V>?

Tags: java, generics

[image]

K and V are guarantee to be either String or Integer.
I've use generics quite a few times, but never `<K extends Comparable<K>, V>`, so I am struggling right now.

Comment: The last one seems to not show error, but I am afraid if I could mess up without knowing exactly the correct one.

And also there seems to be another valid one (no red highlighting in IDE) which I can't recall.

What would you write if you were me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you implement a generic interface, you should always specify the type arguments. You can get away with not specifying them, but then you are using raw types, [which you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

When you *do* specify them, you also need to specify them in a valid way.

First option is wrong because of two reasons:

- When you specify the type arguments, you never rewrite the bounds on that argument, so writing `K extends Comparable<K>` is wrong
- `K` and `V` are not defined anywhere.

Second option is wrong because you rewrote the bounds on `K`. This option differs from the first option in that `K` and `V` *are* defined here - `K` and `V` are the type arguments of `Son`.

Third option compiles, but it uses raw types, which kind of defeats the purpose of using generics in the first place.

Ideally, you would write something like:

```
class Son<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Father<K, V> {

}
```

Note how I did not rewrite the bounds, and defined `K` and `V` as the type arguments for `Son`.

Alternatively, specify a concrete type:

```
class Son implements Father<String, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: About the first one you posted, can the compiler not make inference about K from the interface definition which clearly already has the all the info needed for the class? Why do you have to write again the bound, the K extends comparable thingy instead of just K for the class?

Comment: @AungKhant That's exactly why you _should not_ rewrite the bound.